# Unable to run QML examples using Qt5 UWP 64 bit

Tags: windows, qt, uwp, windows-runtime

I cannot run examples using UWP 64 bit. Device type: Windows Runtime (Local)
Compiler: C: Microsoft Visual c++ Compiler 14.0(amd64) C++: Microsoft Visual c++ Compiler 14.0(amd64) Debugger: Auto-detected CDB at ../x64/cdb.exe Qt version: Qt 5.10.0 MSVC2015 64bit For example while running Gallery example I get this error:
 qt.winrtrunner:

> "C:/Qt/Qt5.10.0/Examples/Qt-5.10.0/quickcontrols2/gallery/debug/AppxManifest.xml" does not exist.
>       qt.winrtrunner: Unable to find a run profile for "C:/Qt/Qt5.10.0/Examples/Qt-5.10.0/quickcontrols2/gallery/debug/gallery.exe"

I tried same example on another PC, it worked on 32bit UWP. Interestingly  Material or Universal themes didn't work. Only native Qt Quick theme works. On the other side everything works nice on Mingw 32bit desktop mode.